# What would be the proper way to store objects in firebase to reorder them later in an easy way?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a list like this

```
    {"ids": [
      {
        "id1": {
          "name": "name1",
          "lastname": "lastname1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id2": {
          "name": "name2",
          "lastname": "lastname2"
          }
      },
      {
        "id3": {
          "name": "name3",
          "lastname": "lastname3"
        }
      },
      {
        "id4": {
          "name": "name4",
          "lastname": "lastname4"
        }
      }
      ]
    }
```

Then I retrieve and display it with this:

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app',
      templateUrl: `
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let id of ids | async">
        {{ id.name }}
        </li>
      </ul>
      `,
    })
    class AppComponent {
    ids: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
      constructor(af: AngularFire) {
        this.ids = af.database.list('/ids');
      }
    }
```

The result:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
```

Let's say I would like to reorder/move some objects, so I get result like this:

```
name3
name1
name2
name4
```

What would be a good way to structure my objects to easily achieve this?
I could add "order" property, update it and order the query by "order" property.

```
    this.ids = af.database.list('/ids',{
          query: {
    orderByChild: 'order'
    }
    });
```

Or maybe I could add previous id key as a property, but how to display the list then, taking "previous" property into consideration? I figure out how to achieve this to avoid future scalability issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you will have to add property for storing order.

Second, you should not be saving this data as array as firebase stores it as object anyway. Instead you should be saving as object.

Check out the following link for more info.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

So, your firebase database should look this.

```
"ids": {
    "id1": {
        "name": "name1",
        "lastname": "lastname1",
        "order": 1
    },
    "id2": {
        "name": "name2",
        "lastname": "lastname2",
        "order": 2
    },
    "id3": {
        "name": "name3",
        "lastname": "lastname3",
        "order": 3
    },
    "id4": {
        "name": "name4",
        "lastname": "lastname4",
        "order": 4
    }
}
```

And you should be querying by `order` property.

Comment: Thank you, that is the solution I was thinking about, but forces me to update every next 'id' when I delete one. I am not sure if this would be an appropriate way to update things when it comes to huge object. I am thinking about storing reference to a previous 'id', but can't figure out how to retrieve results in a expected order then.

Comment: You do not have to update anything when you delete. Your ordering still be reserved. For example you delete object with order: 3. you will have objects with order: 1,2,4 and your ordering will work. Why do you have to update anything on delete?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I might want to create another object and place it on the first place so the natural think is to update all object's order. Or actually set the first order to be <0. I just don't know if this should be the way to go. I would also like to have some kind of human readable consistency in my ordering method just in case. Can't think right now about other edge cases.

Comment: You are right. If you do not want to have negative order  and you want new object in the middle somewhere, you should update other objects. But I think that you will not have large data here, because in large data custom ordering is not so useful. I had the same situation. I allow user to reorder list and I update other objects as well.

Comment: Instead of ordering them with 1,2,3 you can order them with 1000, 2000, 3000. And when you want to insert object on first place you just insert with order 999, 998, 997 etc. You will still have to update after 1000 insert but that's huge improvement. And you can even increase range and order initial items with 10000, 20000, 30000. You update once in a while, but that can even be done on server side.